# How to set Node Environment as Env Variable in the middle of the app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, environment-variables

I know that I can do process.env.NODE_ENV = TEST but it is not working for me. Relevant code below:

test.js

```
import server from "../../src/index.js";

process.env.NODE_ENV = "test";
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);  // returns "test"
chai.use(chaiHttp);

// calls server here with chai-http
```

src/index.js

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

// Some API endpoint here that calls getUserFromUserId

app.listen(port, () => {
  logger.info(`App running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

export default app;
```

user.js

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)  // returns undefined
process.env.NODE_ENV = "test"  // manually sets it here again
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)  // returns test correcly this time
```

So the issue here is that when I run test.js, I am importing, and therefore running user.js before I set my NODE_ENV. Since imports are hoisted I can't bring the env setting earlier either. However, I need the user.js to behave differently when I am testing, and hence I need to set the NODE_ENV before running user.js code. How can I achieve that?

**Edit**:
I tried changing my test script to 'test: SET NODE_ENV=test && mocha'.
This seems to set the node env but I am still facing issue.

user.js

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);  // returns test
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV === "test");  // returns false
process.env.NODE_ENV = "test";
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);  // returns test
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV === "test");  // returns true
```

Somehow the 2 'test' are different? There is also the issue of SET being Windows-specific.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add `user.js` import in your example. You can try to run node process passing env variable like `NODE_ENV=test node ./test.js`. Or use **require** instead of **import**

Comment: I didnt include it in my code snippet because I was not directly importing user.js, I was importing some route function that is importing a controller function that is importing user.js from the service directory, but that import is taken care of.

Comment: I can do a SET NODE_ENV=test in my script but I was wondering if there was another way. I prefer to avoid require if I can (so that all my import statements could be consistent).

Comment: I suppose you need to wrap all this code along with setting `NODE_ENV` to a function and call it wherever is necessary. That way you won't depend pon imports order and so on

Comment: @maksimr see edit above after I tried to set the NODE_ENV in the script call.

Comment: @Samson if you need this only for test as I remember mocha has something like `--require`  which allow executing passed file before tests, so maybe it would help and would be more convenient than passing env var from `npm script`

Comment: IMHO All code solutions would look like hacks if you want to preserve `import` and source `code` untouched  because this is how import works, so no proper way to break this logic (and no need :) )

Comment: Thanks maksimr! I think you are right. Given the situation I think setting the NODE_ENV through script might be the most direct method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I have settled with installing cross-env and doing

"test" : "cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha"

but would love to hear better suggestions.